# Non-smooth DoubleAnimation

Tags: c#, wpf, performance, animation

I am using [`DoubleAnimation`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.animation.doubleanimation.aspx) for zooming and panning in and out of map. My map is an image with huge resolution (15,000 x 8,438). The problem is that on first time the zoom animation is very faltering and not smooth, at second time it`s getting better and so on. How can I make my animation smoother or make some cashing of the image or animation before performing it, or maybe using other form of animation?

My Code:

```
namespace AnimationTest
{

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    ScaleTransform transP;
    TranslateTransform trans2P;

    DoubleAnimation animP;
    DoubleAnimation animYP;
    DoubleAnimation animXP;
    TransformGroup myTransformGroupP;

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        transP = new ScaleTransform();
        trans2P = new TranslateTransform();

        myTransformGroupP = new TransformGroup();
        myTransformGroupP.Children.Add(transP);
        myTransformGroupP.Children.Add(trans2P);

        animP = new DoubleAnimation(1, 20, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));

        animXP = new DoubleAnimation(0, -14000, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));
        animYP = new DoubleAnimation(0, -4000, TimeSpan.FromMilliseconds(3000));
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {

        image1.RenderTransform = myTransformGroupP;
        transP.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleXProperty, animP);
        transP.BeginAnimation(ScaleTransform.ScaleYProperty, animP);

        trans2P.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.XProperty, animXP);
        trans2P.BeginAnimation(TranslateTransform.YProperty, animYP);

    }

}
}
```

Comment: use a small sized image just for the animation ,it will be a little blurry but will be smooth

Comment: I know that, but it`s not what i want

Comment: You may want to use an approach like [mipmaps](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mipmap) and [tiled rendering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiled_rendering)

Comment: This is good approach but for now I need something simpler and fast to create. It is not the main thing in the project, just some add on, each time I need to zoom to specific pre defined location (country)

Comment: i tested your code with an 16384X8192 Image and in my case it does get better after it is allways the same amount of faltering

Comment: your problem is really the size of your image because after trying multiple image sizes i cann tell you they smaller the image get they more fluid the animation becomes

Comment: @DanM, could you please specify what .NET version you are targeting and on what hardware you experiencing this issue with animation performance? I've just checked it with .NET 4.5 WPF project and image 4642x4642 and it runs without any faltering. May be image is not large enough, but that is all what I have near by for quick test.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have not tried your animation approach, i tried to implement my own logic to to this.

First i am inspired by zooming animation used by [Picasa](http://picasa.google.com). So i tried to implement similar type of animation and this works fine for me on my core2duo processor with image size of 10000x5000 without any lag.
This approach consumed a lot of memory, but when i compared my memory usage with [Picasa ImageViewer](http://picasa.google.com) it was almost same. This approach may increase the loading time of your application but this can be handled and not a problem here.

Here is the Code for Main Window Grid that i have Used.

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Height="30" Width="100" Content="Zoom" Click="ButtonZoom_OnClick" />
    <Image RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="HighQuality" Stretch="Uniform" Width="100" Height="100" Grid.Row="1"
           Margin="30" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Source="mad1.jpg" Name="ImageMain"
           x:FieldModifier="private" />

</Grid>
```

Button Click event Code

```
private void ButtonZoom_OnClick(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Task.Factory.StartNew(() =>
        {
            var i = 0;
            while (i++ < 100)
            {
                var i1 = i;
                //var i1 = (-0.00092)*(i*i) + (0.092)*i + 0.2;
                Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
                    {
                        if (i1 < 10 || i1 > 90)
                        {
                            ImageMain.Height += 0.5;
                            ImageMain.Width += 0.5;
                        }
                        else if (i1 < 30 || i1 > 70)
                        {
                            ImageMain.Height += 1;
                            ImageMain.Width += 1;
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            ImageMain.Height += 3;
                            ImageMain.Width += 3;
                        }
                    }));
                Thread.Sleep(30);
            }

        });
}
```

The commented line in this code is a quadratic equation for a smooth animation for acceleration and acceleration of animation. the roots are calculated for starting zooming by 0.2 and half at 2.5 and stops at 0.2 with in range of [0-100]. if you want to create your fully customized animation you may use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/) to check your animation graph. but the simple approach is to use simple control statements to control your animation.

This code is only for zooming your image, your approach will be similar for zoom out.

Comment: I've you code and on my i5@2.6Ghz for some reason it noticeable lagging on the very beginning when the image is quite small. But when it gets larger it animates more smoothly.

Comment: Test your application in **without Debug Mode**

Comment: Yes, its better without Debug, thanks. May be not 100% smooth, but at least usable with huge images.

Answer (score 3):

Have you looked into Microsoft's DeepZoom technology (this is what they use for Bing Maps)? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645050(v=vs.95).aspx#deep_zoom_examples

Answer (score 3):

Since you have not shown any XAML I'll try from the most basic - try to reduce bitmap scaling mode with **RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="LowQuality"** on your image element like this:

```xml
<Image x:Name="image1"
       Source="huge-image.jpg"
       Stretch="Uniform"
       RenderOptions.BitmapScalingMode="LowQuality" />
```

Note, that this is only actual if you targeting **.NET 3.0-3.5** since starting from  **.NET 4.0** the "LowQuality" setting is already set as default, so you have no need to specify it explicitly. But if your zoom-in animation still faltering you could try to change this default scaling from **LowQuality** to even more lower **NearestNeighbor** which, [according to documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.bitmapscalingmode%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

> ...provides performance benefits over LowQuality mode when the software rasterizer is used. This mode is often used to magnify a bitmap.

Also since you are about to show large image with some loss of quality it may be better to specify **UseLayoutRounding="True"** on your image or it parent element to improve image quality.

Comment: Ok, I've finally tested this on huge images and it really not solve the issue completely something after 8k x 8k resolution, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use a cached composition. Render your map but assign a BitmapCache to the CacheMode property and set the RenderAtScale to a value larger than 1. If you zoom into your map 5x you should use the RenderAtScale with this value as it caches the image for this type of zoom.
This may result in a much higher memory consumption but may smooth the scrolling.

Further more Nolonar may be right. You may need to create mipmaps for the image and provide tile rendering to partially load seen tiles as your image is quite large.

Comment: Thank you! Maybe you can refer me to some example of how to accomplish this?

Comment: Well the basics are quite simple. Your map should receive the Bitmapcache by:  obj.CacheMode = new BitmapCache(5); The cache creates the cached size. However I just realized this won't work for you as it means that the map will be stored 5 times as large in the cache eating up even more memory and requiring more computation. I think you will need to get into mipmapping and tile rendering. Sorry